# log4j2 Appender change rollingfilename when is triggered

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

Based on the standard log4j2.xml file, I would like to insert the "Completed" string to the previous file, when switching to a new one.

Something like: "logs/app-09-18-2017_Completed.log"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" 
       filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log"
       <PatternLayout>
          <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
       </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
       <AppenderRef ref="SYSTEM_OUT"/>
       <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
 </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaing the `filePattern` to

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" 
       filePattern="logs/app_completed-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log">
```

shall help you. Since it treats the pattern as a string where the the `DateFormat` `%d` or the integer count `%i` is replaced.

Comment: nullpointer,
 Thanks for so prompt answer.
I forgot the most significant part - the inserted string has to be "Completed-HHmmss" one. And the

Comment: nullpointer,
 Thanks for so prompt answer.
I forgot the most significant part - the inserted string has to be "Completed-HHmmss" one. And the before being completed, the current file"logs/app-MM-dd-yyy.log" has to be readable while is written, usually by 'tail -f' (it's a Linux workstation).

Comment: *the current file"logs/app-MM-dd-yyy.log" has to be readable while is written, usually by 'tail -f'* that is possible with any file present in the directory being logged by the application.

Comment: Is there any possibity to insert the "Completed-HHmmss" string (for instance "Completed-233412") to the previous filename, while switching to a new one ?

Comment: @Zeev `filePattern=logs/completed-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log` is probably what you're looking for?

Comment: Not exactly ... :)

Comment: Lets name the currently written file: current, and to the completed one: previous. The current is "logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log" i.e. "logs/app-09-18-2017.log". The previous is "logs/app-Completed235015-09-18-2017.log". The "Completed235015" means that the file definitely was completed on this certain time: 23:50:15. Is it possible to configure ? Or perhaps create a plugin and to implement it in Java, though I'm not sure how to do it ... :)